# Is it okay to run multiple invocations of 'git merge' simultaneously?

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a tool that is based on git but does some rather unusual stuff, and I need to know: is it safe to run multiple instances of `git merge --ff-only [remote-branch]` at once to get the newest commit available on any of them?  All the remotes will be on the same line of commits.  I'd like to be able to have my tool just spawn them all and let git sort it out, but I need to know if this will cause problems.  Does anyone know enough about git internals to say one way or the other?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the use case? Can different remotes have conflicting changes? Couldn't you get a baseline doing `git fetch` and the use `git log` to pick the latest one canonically?

Comment: I'm using git to distribute some data across a bunch of machines.  No conflicts can occur because there is only one ultimate source of new commits.  "Merge" is really a misnomer in this case, because all I want to do is see if a remote tracking branch is newer and update the master branch and working copy if so.  Most of the merges will be no-ops, but sometimes an update will be propagating and in rare cases there might be two or three remotes that each have the same updated commit at more or less the same time.

Comment: Then a `git fetch`from all remotes, then a `git merge --rebase` to the most ahead remote head you just fetched is doing what you want.

Comment: Is checking which head of N remotes is most up to date much faster than just running all the merges one after another?

Comment: Octopus-style, forced-dast-forward merge would probably be less code for the same result. Doing merges one after another would work, too, but it can't be concurrent :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing --ff-only merges, why don't you just inspect the references with `git branch --contains` or some other way to see if the old commit is reachable and then do either a reset or update-ref?

This should be very fast and would potentially avoid updating the working directory.

Comment: Thanks, that actually sounds really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Git uses locks to prevent concurrent access, in worst case your merge attempt will fail with something like `lock file exists` error.

BTW, the merge allow multiple merge, there is an octopus merge strategy.

Comment: Octopus merge is cool, however the OP mentions `--ff-only`, which is never going to happen in the case of an octopus, right?

Comment: @Romain Yep, probably... But if all branches would have the same commits (i.e. just something like backup copies of each other), it could work, however I've not tried myself and have doubts...

Comment: An octopus merge does make a MERGE_HEAD which contains all the refs to each commit that's being merged.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, why don't you just merge each remote branch in turn, rather than spawning them simultaneously?

```
 #!/bin/sh
 set -e
 for rtb in origin/master github/master gitorious/master
 do
     git merge --ff-only $rtb
 done
```

If `HEAD` already contains one of the remote-tracking branches, the merge still returns successfully, saying `Already up-to-date.`

Comment: I am doing that, but it turns out that 'git merge' can randomly take upwards of a minute if the IO works out poorly, so I wanted to be able to have the thread responsible for this go do something else.  I may just put all the merging in its own thread, serialized, and be done with it.

Comment: Right.  There should be very little IO involved in traversing the commit graph to work out if a merge is necessary.  In most cases, I suspect that the majority of the IO is in actually checking out the new commit after finding that a fast-forward merge was necessary, in which case your best win is in finding the most recent commit, and just merging that one.